# Django Invalid block tag expected 'empty' or 'endfor'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display list of clinics but I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /clinics/
Exception Value: Invalid block tag: 'c.name', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'
```

Here is the clinicList.html

```
{% for c in clinics %}
    {% c.name %}
{% endfor %}
```

here is the views

```
def clinicList(request):
    d = getVariables(request,dictionary={'page_name':""})
    d.update({'clinics': Clinic.objects.all()})

    return render(request, 'm1/clinicList.html', d)
```

here is url.py

```
url(r'^clinics/$', views.clinicList, name='clinicList'),
```

Comment: shouldn't it be {{ c.name }}

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can't believe I made such a trivial mistake. You can post it as an answer and I can mark it checked

Comment: Everyone needs that kind of help now and then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you should have `{{ c.name }}`